# Multithreading multiple forms

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have one main form that starts on program in program.cs as `Application.Run(new Form1());`. It opens object of 2 different forms as:

```
Form2 obj1 = new Form2();
obj2.Show();

Form3 obj2 = new Form3();
obj3.Show();
```

Each form has `Thread.Sleep(10000)` code but the problem is that on one's Thread.Sleep execution, whole programs sleeps. I thought if one form's Thread.Sleep runs, it will not stop other form and will not affect those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All GUI components run on a single GUI thread therefore if you sleep that thread *everything* running on that thread sleeps, which in your case means all of your forms.

If you need a particular form to wait for something to happen then there are various ways of doing that, however, you need to be a bit more clear in your question as to what exactly it is you are waiting for.

Comment: You need to use threading. This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c

Comment: @Samich yes you do - but my point is the OP hasn't made it clear as to *why* he needs the form to sleep in the first place, there are possibly neater ways of doing what it is he needs i.e. a `Timer`. Also, the question you link to isn't even on the same topic it refers to how to update a GUI from another thread...

Comment: Hey, it wasn't comment to your answer, it just addition to your comment. Sorry if I wasn't clear. :)

Comment: @Samich no worries, you should put your comment on the actual question then and not my answer as the OP would get a notification.

Comment: @james, can you also please reply on my next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150298/opening-a-form-multiple-times-from-a-static-class-which-is-called-from-different

Comment: @James, can you also please reply on my next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150298/opening-a-form-multiple-times-from-a-static-class-which-is-called-from-different