# Opening a Form multiple times from a static class which is called from different forms

Tags: c#, class, static, static-methods

If I open a Form named FormX that does some processing on its public (not static) variable "Var". "Var" is set from a calling form and processed and returned for output. I open it from multiple forms multiple times during execution. All forms are running simultaneously. It works fine because each FormX is opened using a seperate instance of an object from its parent form. But I have a public static class "Abc" in my project which is accessible to all forms and if I add a code:

```
public static class Abc
{
  public static string Open_form(string Var)
  {
    FormX Obj = new FormX();
    Obj.Var = Var;
    Obj.Show();
    Obj.Process_Var();
    Var = Obj.Var;
    Obj.Close();
    return Var;
  }
}
```

and call it somewhere from the forms (and multiple times) like:

```
Form1_Load()
{
  //Some operations
  MessageBox.Show(Abc.Open_form("ABC"));

  //Some operations
  MessageBox.Show(Abc.Open_form("XYZ"));
}

Form2_Load()
{
  //Some operations
  MessageBox.Show(Abc.Open_form("123"));

  //Some operations
  MessageBox.Show(Abc.Open_form("456"));
}
```

Form1 and Form2 are opened from a main Form as:

```
Form1 obj1 = new Form1();
obj1.Show();

Form2 obj2 = new Form2();
obj2.Show();
```

Then will it cause any problem? Will there be any problem in the processing of variable "Var" if two forms call the static call at the same time? One more question, should I call `FormX.Dispose();` after `FormX.Close();` Why and why not? Any benefit of `FormX.Dispose()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `FormX.Var` is a `static` property or field, then yes, there may be issues when it is used by multiple threads or objects at the same time. If `FormX.Var` is not `static`, then no, there should be no issues.

Rule of thumb: Always call `Dispose` on any object that implements `IDisposable`. The GC has a means of calling this for you, but it's always the best practice to call it yourself. To facilitate this, use C#'s `using` keyword. The syntax below automatically calls `Dispose`.

```
using (FormX Obj = new FormX())
{
    ...
}
```

You rarely need to call `Close` directly. Looking at your code, it appears that you want to display FormX as a *modal* form. That is, you want the user to work with the Form and maybe hit an OK button when they're done. Then you're reading off the value of the `Var` property to get the information the user has entered. In this scenario, you need to call `ShowDialog` instead of `Show`. The `ShowDialog` call will only return when the form is closed. Calling `Close` after `ShowDialog` has no effect because the form is already closed.

All told, I believe your code should look like this:

```
    public static string Open_form(string Var)
    {
        using (FormX Obj = new FormX())
        {
            Obj.Var = Var;
            Obj.ShowDialog();
            Obj.Process_Var();
            return Obj.Var;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. "Var" is not static.

Comment: I wanted to shift the common code of opening a form from each form's code to a common class perhaps which can be called in a single line from each form.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in your post that indicates "multithreading", nor that your forms "are running simultaneously". Therefore, you `FormX.Var` value is fine.

Comment: Ok. I wanted to shift the common code of opening a form from each form's code to a common class perhaps which can be called in a single line from each form.

Comment: There *is* a potential issue here even without multithreading. Suppose that Ankit actually did mean to display these forms modelessly using `Show` instead of `ShowDialog`. (I realize the code above has a `Close` immediately after the `Show` call, which is problematic, but suppose he corrected this.) In that scenario, you could have multiple forms open at the same time, and if `FormX.Var` is static, it could have an impact despite being single-threaded.